# How to add custom text for the empty first name attribute of a subscriber by using AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

[image]I'm trying to add custom text (ie. "**Dear User,**" instead of just "**Dear ,**") for the empty  first name attribute while triggering the email.

Can anyone help me to fix this by using AMPscript ??

Getting error after adding this code.

%%[

SET @FirstName = FirstName

IF NOT EMPTY(@FirstName) THEN
SET @Salutation = CONCAT(Dear,CONCAT(" ", @Firstname))
ELSE
SET @Salutation = "Dear User"

]%%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super simple.

```
%%[

SET @FirstName = [First Name]

IF NOT EMPTY(@FirstName) THEN
SET @Salutation = CONCAT("Dear ", @FirstName, ",")
ELSE
SET @Salutation = "User"
ENDIF
]%%
```

Then in content you just add %%=v(@Salutation)=%%

e.g.

```
<table><tr><td>Dear %%=v(@Salutation)=%%,</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: It throws me an error.. I'm sending through guided send by using list.

Comment: sorry forgot to close the if statement. will update code accordingly

Comment: :(  Again Error.
Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
An Error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: CONCAT(Dear,CONCAT("",!Firstname)) MemberID:****** JobID:0 The specified attribute or custom object name was not found for this client.......

Comment: concat line should be `set @saluation = concat("Dear ",@FirstName)`

Comment: was rushing again, forgot the " around dear.

Comment: I usually add spaces at beginning and end of strings in concat as separate fields. I find it is usually safer during editing to ensure it is not accidentally erased.

Comment: Mail Triggered without error. But I am seeing Dear User for all the subscriber.
Note: I'm using Lists from Subscribers for testing purpose. (i.e Subscriber>Lists)

Comment: make sure that the attribute you are using to set @FirstName does not have a space in it, if so you will need to house in brackets. ( e.g. [First Name]).  Otherwise you can pull via AttributeValue().

Comment: It works :)
Will the code work for Data extension as well ??

Comment: yes - just replace the list attribute with the appropriate data extension field name.

Comment: not a problem! glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do it this way:

```
%%[

var @FirstName
set @FirstName = AttributeValue("First_Name") /* handle null gracefully */

]%%
Dear %%=iif(empty(@FirstName),"User",@FirstName)=%%,
```

Comment: User text comes for all the subscribers.

Comment: It shouldn't if your sending Data Extension or List has a column or Attribute named `FirstName`.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I've checked the Data Extension property and the field name is set to "FIRST_NAME". So I've to modify to something like this right ? i.e SET @FirstName =  FIRST_NAME
Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two MAIN OPTIONS when deciding on salutations.

**Assuming the first name column on your data extension is called "FIRST_NAME".**

OPTION 1. When first name is blank in your data extension, and you want to add a default name so you never get a "Dear ," scenario.

`Dear %%[if not empty(FIRST_NAME) then]%%%%FIRST_NAME%%%%[else]%%Client%%[endif]%%,`

or

OPTION 2. You want to simply hide the salutation altogether when the first name is blank and simply begin the first paragraph. Note: You will most likely want a line break so you need to add two HTML breaks immediately after the comma.

`%%[if not empty(FIRST_NAME) then]%%Dear %%FIRST_NAME%%,%%[endif]%%`

While you could create variables and use set commands in an AMPscript block, not sure that approach makes the most sense here.  I personally save these two options as HTML code snippets and add them on the fly as needed.